.NET Core 8 cookie value getting formatted
I have an api which I migrated from .NetFramework to .net core 8.
The API returns a string a,b. While the string value is properly stored in .Net Framework. In .net core 8, it is getting replaced with a%2cb.
I have appended the cookie using
cookieValue = "a,b";
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new()
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
    Secure = true
};

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("test", cookieValue, cookieOptions);

I was expecting a,b to be set in the browser. Is this a bug in .Net core 8?

Please show us the raw Set-Cookie header you see in your HTTP response (e.g. in Chrome DevTools or Wireshark).

you'll see here that comma is not allowed in cookie-value:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes "Encoding: Many implementations perform URL encoding on cookie values. However, this is not required by the RFC specification. The URL encoding does help to satisfy the requirements of the characters allowed for ."
